# Form field value doesn't post

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress, forms

I am fetching some values from a table using

```
$match = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $tablename WHERE approve = 0");
```

In the database all fields are set to text and 'latin1_swedish_ci' collation.

I then insert these into input fields:

```
<input type="hidden" name="tID" value="<?php echo $row->id ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="first" value="<?php echo $match[0]->team_one ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="second" value="<?php echo $match[0]->second ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="winner" value="<?php echo $match[0]->winner ?>">
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Eo3G.png

Then I'm retrieving all the values when I click the submit button using:

```
$tID = $wpdb->escape($_POST['tID']);
$first = $wpdb->escape($_POST['first']);
$second = $wpdb->escape($_POST['second']);
$win = $wpdb->escape($_POST['winner']);
```

The issue is that whenever I have the input field with a value of "$match[0]->second", on submit it always refreshes the page and says the same page cannot be found (error 404)!! also I can never retrieve the value of $second. Any other value is fine but just not second..

Answer (score 0):

the issue was the input field had a "name" of "second" which for some reason caused a lot of bugs. Changing the name fixed the issue